# Devise in Rails Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rapidfire-gem

I'm quite new to rails, and especially engines; where is the gemspec where I can add in

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.add_dependency "devise"
end
```

as per devise documentation?

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine

I have tried going to the engine.rb, rapidfire.rb but to no avail... requiring 'devise' in engine.rb doesn't work as some other posts have said :(

Comment: did you run `bundle install` after adding it to the gemspec?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to add it to gemspec - is that just as i said before, adding require to engine.rb?

Comment: yeah that's all good, but you have to execute `bundle install` when changing the gemspec. (it's like modifying your Gemfile).
What's the error? like: `LoadError: cannot load such file -- devise`?

Comment: It's just coming up as `undefined local variable or method new_user_session_path`- it all worked up until I added in links to the paths

Comment: Just made some tweaks and now I'm getting `uninitialized constant MyEngine` after following the guide further